# Word for people who take everything literally?

Tags: word-request

I’ve asked about this years ago and people took it the wrong way, every answer was about being intellectually challenged or not understanding figurative language. I don’t mean that. I teach Logic at universities and I tell my students that in logic everything is to be taken literally once formalised. One good example of a phrase that means completely different things in figurative versus literal interpretations is “I’ve slept with my sister”. I use that example in class.

Is there a word for intelligent people taking everything at face value, literally, and refusing to even consider figurative meanings? I mean, a word, either noun or adjective, for the behaviour I’m trying to instill into my students?

Comment: I don't think there is an exact adjective for taking everything literally  *as a positive, intentional quality*.  There is [*literal-minded*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/literal-minded), but that tends to mean something like "obtuse, unimaginative".

Comment: A literalist would be my choice. "I've slept with my sister" is ambiguous because it has two meanings but not due to figurative and literal. It has two literal meanings.

Comment: See on ELU: [What would be a word for describing a tendency to take the literal meaning of words above the accepted meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/161114/191178)

Comment: @Lambie Do you mean that sleeping and having sexual intercourse are literally the same thing? I can assure you that’s not the case because I sleep every night! Sleeping means sleeping and drinking means drinking. Having sexual intercourse and drinking alcohol are figurative meanings.

Comment: Not at all. to sleep with someone has **two literal meanings**: 1) sleep next to someone in the same place or bed 2) to have sex with. So, it's semantically ambiguous, not literally versus figuritively.

Comment: You can say something along the lines that when you're working in formal logic, you have to be very literal and read only what's written, but I don't think there's a word that means that and also lacks an implication that the person is being stupid or intentionally obtuse. That's the whole point, right?  You don't want to be like that in normal everyday activity, but when you're using formal logic you have to stop interpreting and say exactly what you mean with mathematical precision.

Comment: @Lambie The only literal meaning of “to sleep” is to sleep. What’s your source for your claim that another literal meaning of “to sleep” is “to have sexual intercourse”? And if you think it is now a literal sense, surely you would have to admit that it started as non-literal. Probably as an euphemism.

Comment: @DarthPaeudonym Well, I do want to be like that in normal everyday life, but that’s a different topic 

Comment: Merriam Webster: sleep with
phrasal verb
slept with; sleeping with; sleeps with
informal
: to have sex with (someone) ///It is not figurative. It is a phrasal verb. So: I sleep with my sister can be a phrasal verb or NOT. My baby sleeps with a stuffed animal.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I see. Your criterion is dictionary appearance. Didn’t know phrasals couldn’t be figurative.

Comment: @Lambie — [LITERAL | English meaning - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/literal) says: "*A literal translation of a text is done by translating each word separately, **without looking at how the words are used together in a phrase** or sentence.*".  So "to sleep with someone" has only one literal meaning. Whether something is a phrasal verb is irrelevant to being literal.

Comment: @RayButterworth Well, I certainly agree with that, as a translator with 35 years of experience. It also says: A literal translation of a text is done by translating each word separately, without looking at how the words are used together in a phrase or sentence: **Her translation is too literal, resulting in unnatural-sounding prose./sleep with/ my sister is not /sleep/ with my sister**. However, we are not translating as regards this question. We are parsing it. Also, literal translation is considered a "bad thing", not a good one as their sample sentence shows...

Comment: @Lambie says '*literal translation is considered a "bad thing"*'. — But not in the context of this question.  The OP talks of"*the behaviour I’m trying to instill into my students*". It's about a formal logic course, and for that one *must* take everything literally. The same need for literalism would also apply to other situations, such as legal documents.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm afraid you are mixing up two fields; translation and logic are two different fields. Formal logic does not mean you take everything literally. Formal logic is every statement has to be True or False. So, "I slept/with my sister" can be T or F. Or: "I slept with/my sister" can be T or F. Both would be acceptable in terms of truth statements. But they are different statements.

Comment: @Lambie Literal translation is necessary in my field, analytic philosophy. You change one word, you change the intended meaning. I don’t know if you teach logic but yes, in formal logic everything once formalised is to be taken literally. And no, formal logic doesn’t mean that every statement has to be true or false. You can have a formal many-valued logic.

Comment: @Lambie Although you are right in that you can have different propositions expressed by the same sentence.

Comment: @user354948 Taken literally does not mean that the statements have to be literal. You could use highly figurative statements and still do logic. **All woodland faeries are green**. And: Many-valued logic (also multi- or multiple-valued logic) refers to a propositional calculus in which there are **more than two truth values**. Truth values refers to true or false, right? Of course, I don't teach logic.

Comment: @Lambie Interpreting something literally, yes, makes the formalised proposition literal. After interpretation, there’s no difference between what x means in the system and what x is taken to mean. A statement about fairies would have to be taken literally, as any other, or reformulated in the symbols if it wasn’t intended literally. Saying that fairies are green just says that fairies are green. No figuration there. Truth values are not necessarily true and false. You can have other values, such as “indeterminate” and even more exotic ones.

Comment: @Lambie. So if I understood you correctly you say that there’s literal translation and then there’s literal “parsing”. If that’s the case, as Ray correctly surmised, I was referring to literal as it is used in translation.

Comment: @Lambie Anyway, your answer, “literalist”, is a good one. Thanks.

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks, Ray. So I guess from now on every time I say “literal” I will have to clarify “literal as in translation, not as in parsing” :)

Comment: You know something? I am actually a (natural language) translator and you guys are misusing these terms. I was telling Ray Butterworth that he misread that thing about literal translation [**of natural languages**, like French to English, or Chinese to Russian]. Literal translation from one **language to another** is a bad thing. And "literal parsing" is not "a thing". Parsing utterances and sentences is, however, a thing.

Comment: @Lambie "*All woodland faeries are green.*" is a statement that can be true, false, unknown, etc., but, unless you know of some special meaning that I don't know about (e.g. "woodland faeries" is a slang expression for frogs), this is not a *figurative* statement. Most people would understand "woodland faeries" as referring to faeries that live in woodlands, and that is a *literal* interpretation of the words (which is independent of the truth of the statement).

Comment: @RayButterworth Woodland faeries do not exist in the real. That was my point. Logic is not related to figurative or literal. Logic is related to the truth value of statements. literal versus figurative are not useful terms for teaching logic.

Comment: @Lambie says "*literal versus figurative are not useful terms for teaching logic*".  Bingo!  You got it. That's the whole point of this. ¶ By eliminating the use of figurative language many instances of ambiguity are also removed, without changing the intended meaning.  Without figurative expressions, "I slept with" and "I had sex with" become two completely different facts, with no confusion about what either of them means because everything is understood to have only its literal meaning.

Comment: @Lambie says "*Woodland faeries do not exist in the real.* — So logically that implies that the statement "*All woodland faeries are green*" is true.  But it is true only if we have agreed that figurative interpretation is not allowed.  Without that, someone could say that they interpret "woodland faeries" as a term meaning "frogs", and so understand it as saying that "frogs are green", which is usually true, but not always, and so whatever logical argument was being made falls apart. Disallowing figurative interpretation avoids that problem.

Comment: @Lambie I wonder how would you decide on the truth value of a sentence without first interpreting it (and that requires talking about literal vs figurative) to know what proposition it is expressing. Before checking whether fairies exist or not, you need to know what’s meant by “fairies”. In this way, talking about literal vs figurative is very useful for teaching logic. I also wonder why you would believe otherwise.

Comment: @RayButterworth Totally. Good example with the frogs. I just answered something very similar in more technical language.

Comment: @Lambie If you think that your example about fairies was figurative, I’m starting to doubt that you know what “figurative” means.

Comment: @Lambie How did Ray Butterworth misread that thing about literal translation? You first said “I certainly agree with that, as a translator with 35 years of experience.” and then said that he had misread it.

Comment: @user354948 He misread its application to the question here.  Of course, I agree with Cambridge's definition of **literal translation**. I don't agree that the concept applies to the question here.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I see!

Answer (score 2):

[Literal-minded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literal-minded): Understanding words and statements only in the most basic and ordinary way and not having much imagination.

[Literalist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literalist): A person who takes things literally, especially someone who adheres to a strict interpretation of a text or doctrine.

Please note that your example "I’ve slept with my sister" has two literal meanings. Neither of the two meanings are figurative as Lambie pointed out.

Comment: The late, great Christopher Hitchens often warned that humanity needs to be saved from "literalists".

Comment: Yes, two literal meanings, as I was the first to say. Usually, when an answer repeats what's in a comment, credit is given to the person who made the comment. But no worries.

Comment: edited my answer to credit you. sorry about that!

Comment: As explained in my OP, “unamiginative” is not one of the implications I want to include. Lambie was also the first to suggest “literalist”, which is the only good suggestion so far. Ok, I accept that English forms a different literal meaning in phrasal expressions. But I needed someone else to confirm given that Lambie’s example of figurative statement shows that he doesn’t understand what “figurative” means, and so I couldn’t trust his understanding of the antonym, “literal”.

Comment: @Jaime That guy thought the war in Irak was a good idea, so… humanity needs to be saved from people like him.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes. That was his big one.